# javaws does not pass -J VM arguments when using remote jnlp file

Tags: java-8, java-web-start

when I launch my application with local JNLP file

```
javaws -J-Xmx64m myApplication.jnlp
```

the application will run with `-Xmx64m`.

When I launch my application with remote jnlp file

```
javaws -J-Xmx64m "http://myserver/myApplication.jnlp"
```

then the jp2launcher seems to download the JNLP file and spawn new jp2launcher that runs my application. However the `-J` parameters are not passed to the new spawned jp2launcher.

I can verify this with JVisualVM.

Is this expected behavior? How can I pass `-Xmx` and other options to my application without specifying them inside the JNLP file (e.g. max-heap-size)?

I am using Java 8 on Windows 7+.

Thank you, Jan

Comment: Just wondering why wont you put `-Xmx64m` not into your JNLP?

Comment: We allow users to run application with different memory settings from 512m (32bit) to 4GB and more in the future. Each jnlp file must be signed and bundled inside a (distinct) jar file.

Comment: Are `myApplication.jnlp` and `http://myserver/myApplication.jnlp` the same?

Comment: Yes, local jnlp was downloaded from the server.